# Get notification from Microsoft Graph when deleting event occurrence

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have subscribed to events (`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events`) push notification.

When I delete one event of recurrence master event, I receive UPDATED notification with id of master event and not specific occurrence event id.

How can I know which event was deleted without comparison with all previous recurrence events? And not receive only master id event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you "delete" and occurrence, you're technically not deleting an entity. You're actual adding an exception to the master's recurrence pattern. This is why you're receiving a notification that the master was updated rather than a notification that an event was deleted.

You can see the list of event occurrences and exceptions by calling the [`/instances`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_list_instances). This will return a collection of [event objects](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) for a given master. You can determine if an object is an occurrence or an exception by looking at the `type` property (possible values are `SingleInstance`, `Occurrence`, `Exception`, or `SeriesMaster`).

Comment: This works great if you update a occurrence, e.g. by changing the start time. In that case when you call /instances you correctly get an exception.

On the other hand if you delete an occurrence there is no exception when you call /instances. The corresponding occurrence json object is simply removed from the response in that case. This is not really handy when you get an update. How do you know which is to remove? Only way seems to re-import everything. 

Does somebody have better suggestions?