# Recurring event is not returning actual Id in notification

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When user delete a occurance of an event in recurring event, it triggers the notification in the system. I further needed the exact item to be deleted details:
But following code is returning only one Unique Id:

```
if (folder.WellKnownFolderName == WellKnownFolderName.Calendar)
            {
                IAppointmentsRespository appointmentsContext = new AppointmentsRepository(new SubscriptionContext());
                Appointment appointments = await Appointment.Bind(subscription.service, itemEvent.ItemId, BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                Item item =appointments as Item;
}
```

itemEvent.ItemId is the parent Id, How can I get the actual Item from it. Like "appointments as Item" is also giving the same Id like:

> AAMkAGU4NGE5NThhLTI1MTktNGViZC1hZGRiLTBhNGU4MWY5MjIwZQBGAAAAAABBF6IagdxkTJSLXw35We4aBwB9iKZNjeQ9TIySKe6QD1m5AAAAAAEKAAB9iKZNjeQ9TIySKe6QD1m5AAARH8IHAAA=

I need a unique Id of the Item.

[image: Recuurance events]

Answer (score 0):

You could get iCalUId parameter. It is shared by all instances of an event across different calendars.

For more information, you could refer to these links:

[Get notification from Microsoft Graph when deleting event occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248906/get-notification-from-microsoft-graph-when-deleting-event-occurrence)

[event resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event)