# How to notify all attendees if a group event deleted?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When I am deleting an event from group calendar using the following api:

```
DELETE groups/${groupId}/calendar/events/${eventId}
```

How can I send updates to reflect this in all attendees' calendar?

Comment: Not sure, you could refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248906/get-notification-from-microsoft-graph-when-deleting-event-occurrence

Comment: If they were attendees of the event, they should be notified automatically that the event was canceled. Is that not what you're seeing?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur if I delete it from group calendar then no-one will get the cancellation event. It is sending cancellation only if I delete it from my personal calendar.

Comment: Is it sending the cancelation if you delete the event via Outlook instead of the API?

Comment: No, it won't send any cancellation if you delete it from group calendar either from outlook or api.